# Dynamically Creating Textboxes and DropDown Boxes for input form

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am working on a Nutrition Program that would allow a user to enter in the nutrition information for a item. [image: Nutrition Grid]

this is what my input form looks like every time a user clicks the plus button I need to create three new text boxes and a drop down box which would look like the above example. [image]

This is what I am using right now but it only creates the textboxes for the first click. I need create the textboxes and combo boxes on every time the user clicks the add button.

Comment: why not create a usercontrol with that information and add a new instance of your usercontrol with each button click. Not that what you're asking can't be done.

Comment: is clickCount a global variable ?

Comment: i think after postback, the textbox will disappear because it is not in the aspx file. You can check it by inspect the element where every time postback, the ID will increase and the previous textbox is missing. Thus, you need to recreate the previous textbox after postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm,

I managed to do this myself using ViewStates it took alot of code but it works this is adding the controls on button click.

[image]

This is re-adding the controls on postback

[image]

And this is the results[image]